# How to run a program automatically on my terminal login in unix

Tags: unix

Is it possible to write a shell script that automatically starts running whenever i login to my unix terminal? Please provide any reference material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your script inside your `.profile` . `.profile` is executed whenever you log in. If a `.profile` currently doesn't exist in your home directory, create one!

Comment: We are using putty to remote login. Can I modify my home directory in this case?

Comment: Even I use putty remote login. But your home directory has nothing to do with the way you log in. Just say `cd $HOME` from wherever you are. Create a new `.profile` there and add your script inside it

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your shell. Assuming you are using bash, you can add the command to .bash_profile in your home directory.